# Is there a way to extract a key from a dictionary by using a filtering method

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, filter, collections, key

I set up a class of collection, and I created an object containing a dictionary.
I created a method called pluck(self, key) that should return a new Collection with all the values of the key I sent, and I'm used with another method's that I created before (map and filter - Both methods of collection).

class Collection(object):

```
def __init__(self,iterable = None):
    # param iterable: imutable collection
    if iterable == None:
        self.Iterable = ()
    else:
        self.Iterable = tuple(iterable)
    return None


def map(self, *callbacks):
    '''
    :param callbacks: List of function to apply on each element in 'self.Iterable'
    :return: New mapped collection
    '''
    c =Collection(self.Iterable)
    tmp = Collection()
    for item in callbacks:
        for item2 in c.Iterable:
            tmp = tmp.append(item(item2))
        c = Collection(tmp.Iterable)
    return c


def filter(self, *callbacks):
    '''
    :param callbacks: List of function to apply on each element in 'self.Iterable'
    :return:  New filtered collection
    '''
    return Collection(item for item in self.Iterable if CallbacksFilter(item, callbacks) == True)


def CallbacksFilter(item, callback):
    for f in callback:
        if f(item) == False:
            return False
    return True
```

when I try to run pluck method:

```
def pluck(self, key):

    return self.values() if type(self.first()) is not dict else Collection(self.Iterable).filter(self.map(lambda x, y: dict([(i,x[i]) for i in x if i in set(y)])))


c3 = Collection([{'name': 'Joe', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'Jane', 'age': 13}])
c3.pluck('age')
```

I expect to output " Collection(20,13)" but I'm getting this error:

*TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'*

How can I fix this error?

Note: If the internal elements are not dictionaries, then a copy of the current collection returned.

Comment: If you have a solution, you should post it as an answer of its own instead of including it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The method I wrote is incorrect and does not return any result, as I mentioned above.

```
def pluck(self, key):

    return self.values() if type(self.first()) is not dict else Collection(self.Iterable).filter(self.map(lambda x, y: dict([(i,x[i]) for i in x if i in set(y)])))
```

The Map method returns the result by applying the lambda function given to it on each dictionary of the collection.

```
def map(self, *callbacks):
'''
:param callbacks: List of function to apply on each element in 'self.Iterable'
:return: New mapped collection
'''
c =Collection(self.Iterable)
tmp = Collection()
for item in callbacks:
    for item2 in c.Iterable:
        tmp = tmp.append(item(item2))
    c = Collection(tmp.Iterable)
return c
```

So when we run the following code:

```
def pluck(self, key):
    '''
    :param key: Dictionary key (13)
    :return: Return a new Collection with value of each key.
    '''
         return "Collection{}".format(Collection(self.map(lambda index: index[key])).Iterable)

c3 = Collection([{'name': 'Joe', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'Jane', 'age': 13}])
c3.pluck('age')
```

we get the right result:

> > > Collection(20,13)